# Publishing an addon to Blenders main branch

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I wrote an import/export script for a 3D model format some time ago and would now like to have it added to my portfolio by somehow putting it into Blenders main branch (make it somewhat official and credible).

Is there some group i need to post my addon to for review? How is that process going?

Comment: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Process/Addons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal would be to make your addon a contrib.

This can be achieved at https://developer.blender.org/.
Here, your addon will undergo two types of reviews; function and source code.

For the function review, read : https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Process/Addons .

For the source code review, read : https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Tools/Code_Review .

Comment: Yes, contrib is what i want. Thanks alot!